# Symfony 2.1 Doctrine in Newly Created Bundles

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

Wondering if anybody else has run into this issue. In summary, we upgraded from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.1. With Symfony 2.1 if a create a brand new bundle and then an entity to use with Doctrine I get a `"not a valid entity or mapped super class"`. If I place the same exact entity class (with proper path changes) into an existing bundle (created before 2.1) it can be accessed with no problems, even from the new bundle.

Here are the steps.

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace="Core/TestBundle"--format=yml --no-interaction --structure=no --dir=src 
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="CoreTestBundle:Product" --fields="name:string(255) price:float description:text"
```

here is the Product.php code produced

```
<?php

namespace Core\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Core\TestBundle\Entity\Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var float $price
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
 */
private $price;

/**
 * @var text $description
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Product
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set price
 *
 * @param float $price
 * @return Product
 */
public function setPrice($price)
{
    $this->price = $price;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->price;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param text $description
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return text
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
}
```

from here running

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities "Core/TestBundle/Entity/Product"
```

or accessing Product from code runs into
   `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]  Class
   Core\TestBundle\Entity\Product is not a valid entity or mapped super 
   class.` running
    `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
   produces "Nothing to update"

On the other hand, if I use a pre-existing bundle such as ArticleBundle and run the same commands ie

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="CoreArticleBundle:Product" --fields="name:string(255) price:float description:text"
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities "Core/ArticleBundle/Entity/Product"
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

creates the table fine
Also, accessing the Product from the TestBundle as `CoreArticleBundle:Product` works fine.
I tried to compare the bundle configurations etc but couldn't come up with anything.

I also run the db creation scripts as follows.

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
```

Dropped database for connection named dev

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

Created database for connection named dev
All the tables got created except for the Product one.

In addition I created a fixture with the Product object. Same thing. Works when in an existing bundle. Same error as above in the newly created bundle.

Comment: It is normal that you get the error if you don´t run schema:update. What is strange is that schema:update produces "nothing to update". Have you checked that the Entity is really created and that it looks OK? Have you tried running doctrine:schema:create? What is that "from here running"?

Comment: Can you paste the code of the generated Product entity just after php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="CoreTestBundle:Product" --fields="name:string(255) price:float description:text" ?

Comment: "from here running" is supposed to mean "the next step is ..."

Comment: Have you tried running doctrine:schema:create?

Comment: php app/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database for connection named <comment>dev</comment>
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'dev'; database exists. I can try dropping and creating the db?

Comment: php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
Dropped database for connection named <comment>dev</comment>
php app/console doctrine:database:create
Created database for connection named <comment>dev</comment>. Still not "product" table.

Answer (score 2):

Talked to a local expert. Turns out our application is using two ORM managers. In such a case each bundle using the ORM has to be registered in app/config/config.yml. ie

```
entity_managers:
        sql_write:
            connection: sql_write
            mappings:
                CoreUserBundle : ~
                CoreImageBundle : ~
                CoreTestBundle : ~
```

Answer (score 0):

A doctrine:schema:validate should help you finding errors... It will check your mapping, and check if the mapping is sync with the database.

Comment: `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate               


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "doctrine:schema:validate" is not defined.` Is something not installed in my Symfony package?

Comment: Install or update your vendors again... You're using Composer now you updated your sf2 version ?

Comment: Finally updated Doctrine and was able to run `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate' It complained about some other files but nothing about Product. The Product entity seems invisible to Doctrine. Is there a way to force it?

Comment: Check your annotations synthax, Doctrine should see your entity.

Comment: Double checked the annotations. In any case, the same exact code gets recognized in the ArticeBundle(created before 2.1) but not in the TestBundle created after 2.1